# Looking for micro breweries in the Tokyo area

Tags: japan, alcohol

We will spend a couple of days in the Tokyo area and it would be really fun to visit a microbrewery there. So I am looking for microbreweries in the area or places that serve their products.

[image]

([photo](http://www.flickr.com/photos/dklimke/3284472391/) by dklimke)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just happened to stumble over an article in Time Out last year about the Craft Beer scene in Tokyo - managed to find it again with some creative Googling: [Time Out Tokyo: Craft Beer In Tokyo](http://www.timeout.jp/en/tokyo/feature/5278/Craft-beer-in-Tokyo). One of the articles at the bottom of the page lists [Tokyo's best craft beer bars](http://www.timeout.jp/en/tokyo/feature/5263/Tokyos-best-craft-beer-bars). From a quick skim, it seems most are bars that serve craft beer, not clear if there's much in the way of actual breweries you can tour or microbrewpubs.

Answer (score 2):

**Ryujin Shuzo Brewery** (or **Ginko Kura Brewery**) from Tatebayashi, Gunnma Prefecture, is about 80 km far from the capital Tokyo. Oze no Yukidoke IPA (that I tasted) seems to be their most popular beer but they also brew two kinds of sake ([source](https://www.urbansake.com/sake-guide/sake-breweries/ryujin-shuzo/)).